# Wi-fi disappears after rebooting from windows (18.10)

Tags: networking, dual-boot

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed 18.10 version alongside Windows 10. Every time I boot and choose Ubuntu first, the Wi-fi is OK. Although if I choose to reboot in Windows and then select Ubuntu, there are no visible Wi-fi networks.  So now, every time I want Wi-fi in Ubuntu, I have to shutdown my computer completely, boot, choose Ubuntu and then it is all OK. All drivers are checked and installed (no problems with adaptor). Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because of WOL function

> Realtek no link / WOL problem
>   Users with Realtek 8168 8169 8101 8111(C) based NICs (cards / and on-board) may notice a problem where the NIC seems to be disabled on boot and has no Link light. This can usually be found on a dual boot system where Windows is also installed. It seems that using the official Realtek drivers (dated anything after May 2007) under Windows is the cause. These newer drivers disable the Wake-On-LAN feature by disabling the NIC at Windows shutdown time, where it will remain disabled until the next time Windows boots. You will be able to notice if this problem is affecting you if the Link light remains off until Windows boots up; during Windows shutdown the Link light will switch off. Normal operation should be that the link light is always on as long as the system is on, even during POST. This problem will also affect other operating systems without newer drivers (eg. Live CDs). Here are a few fixes for this problem.

To enable WOL on windows 10:

1.Go to `Device Manager`.

2.Expand Network adapters in the device tree, select your Ethernet adapter, right-click it and then select
    `Properties`.

3.Then select the `Power Management` tab and check off
    all three boxes shown below.

4.Next select the `Advanced tab`,
    scroll down in the `Property box` and select `Wake on Magic Packet`
    and ensure that it is `enabled` in the Value list box then click
    `OK`.

---

Comment: I've enabled WOL on Windows but I am still experiencing the issue. I don't know how to test I did it correctly, though.

Comment: And I realized that I didn't have to do it anyways since the "link" light is always on when I reboot.